# how to implement memcache for many categories

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

I am building a web application on google app engine using python and jinja2.  I have a website where users can write posts and I have 15 main categories and each of those has 4 divisions.  Now I want to implement memcache because I have a 20:1 reader to poster ratio but how can I do it without making 60 different keys?  Should I just do it that way?  Or should I hit the database and sort the results and have some parameters on the function that gets those results like so:

```
def posts_cache(update = False, category = None, sport = None):
        key = 'main'
        posts = memcache.get(key)
        if posts is None or update:
                logging.error("DB QUERY")
                posts = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * "
                                        "FROM Post "
                                        "ORDER BY created DESC "
                                        "LIMIT 100",
                                         key)
                posts = list(posts)
                memcache.set(key, posts)
        if category and sport:
            sportcatlist = []
            for post in posts:
                     if post.category == category:
                         if post.sport == sport:
                             sportcatlist.append(post)
            return sportcatlist
        elif category:
            categorylist = []
            for post in posts:
                     if post.category == category:
                            categorylist.append(post)
            return categorylist
        elif sport:
            sportlist = []
            for post in posts:
                     if post.sport == sport:
                            sportlist.append(post)
            return sportlist
        return posts
```

Or is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: I don't think your solution will scale. If you get large numbers of posts then you won't be able to stuff these details into a single memcache record (ok your currently limiting the result set to 100).  I think you should consider splitting the cache up - once for each category.  Also I feel you could make things a lot more efficient by creating summary records for each category as you create posts.  Then when you fetch these you cache them in memcache. (And invalidate the cache when you update a category).

Comment: okay fair enough, I figured I would probably have to head that way at some point.  What do you mean by summary records?  What would they hold in this case?

Comment: Well each time you add a post, you could update a Category record that holds the most recent n keys of posts with that category.  Then you could fetch the first n articles with a single fetch from cache, if no cache then db.get(category_record key) rather than a query.  It means you do all you filtering of categories on writes rather than on queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to do this more efficiently would be to have list of posts per category and content of the post cached separately by predefined key format ('category_%s(category_name)' for categories and 'post_%s(post_key)'. First contains list posts' keys (possibly with some meta-information like last-updated-date if needed, the second - content of the post by key). Under 'key' I mean either serialized datastore key or id in datastore or something else you could use to simply read post from datastore if it's not in memcache. Storing each particular post and categories content separately will be efficient even under huge load including updates as for updated post you invalidate single memcache key, by adding/deleting post you invalidate list for single category, all other memcached data still in place so other requests handled by memcache only. As appengine enforce limits on amount of data can be stored in memcache, it will delete older and rare hit items and keep often-use which is exactly what you need and scales perfectly fine, approach you described will not give you this.
Hope it helps.